ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null when deployed in a third party BaaS
I am using a third party BackendAsAService (Zoho Catalyst) to deploy my web application. My application provides java program compilation as a service. I am using JDK 17. When run local, ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() works perfectly.
But after deployment, ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null. I guess the problem is due to the presence of JRE without JDK in the deployment environment. Is there a way to include some jar to rectify this problem. I am not able to get tools.jar for JDK 17.
I tried bundling the whole JDK with the web app which is increasing the app size drastically and the deployment environment gets stuck. Please provide me a simple solution.
